One or more of the key or foreign key properties are shadow properties and the entity is not being tracked
I have the following entity class:
internal class ServicePackage {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ServiceId")]
    [DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction)]
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

Very rarely, when trying to attach (dbContext.ServicePackages.Attach) an instance of entity that has already been added into the database, I get the following System.InvalidOperationException exception:

The navigation 'ServicePackage.Service' cannot be loaded because one
or more of the key or foreign key properties are shadow properties and
the entity is not being tracked. Relationships using shadow values can
only be loaded for tracked entities.
Stack Trace:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder'1.GetLoadValues(INavigation,
InternalEntityEntry)
← Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder'1.Load(INavigation,
InternalEntityEntry, LoadOptions)
← Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ReferenceEntry.Load(LoadOptions)
← Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.LazyLoader.Load(Object,
String)
← Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
← Castle.Proxies.ServicePackageProxy.get_Service()

What could be the problem and why does the error occur intermittently?
DbContext.OnConfiguring method override:
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(SqlConnectionString);
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

.NET version: 8.0; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version: 8.0.8

Try to find a case that reproduces the error for 100%. We only see valid configuration code and one line of code that, on itself, should not cause the error.
